# When I add more robots equipped with cameras, something is wrong

Tags: camera

Now I am working on the simulation of coordination of a fleet of robots underwater. Each robot is equipped with one or two cameras for acquiring information. The problem is that when each robot is equipped with two cameras, the maximum number of robots is 4; when I try to add the fifth robot, something is wrong, 
"
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
Python script error - object 'Jack.004', controller 'Python1':
" 
Similarly, when each robot is only equipped with one camera, the maximum number of robots is 7; when I try to add the eighth robot, something is wrong, not just the errors mentioned before, the color of environment rendered also changes and the environment could not be used.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but that sounds like an awesome use of BGE. Where can I learn more about your project?

Comment: What is your version of blender?
Can you show us your code?
If you add 4 robot by code, and try to duplicate "manually" the fith does it work or you have the same issue?

Comment: the version of blender is blender 2.6.9. Of course I could shown my code, but how? I am sorry I have no idea about that. When I try to duplicate the fifth, I have the same problem.